# RegEx.Match not returning expected results

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to build a regular expression that does matches only string2 below.

string 1: (ABC12: CPBI, OTCBB:CPBI)

string 2: (ABC12: CPBI OTCF CPBI)

Following is my C# code

```
private static Regex rxSymbol = new Regex(@"(?<=:)[&/\w -]+\s*(?=\))", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace ); 

rxSymbol.IsMatch(ticker)
```

isMatch statement is returning true for string1. When I tried to get the exact match using `rxSymbol.Match(ticker)`, this is matching 'CPBI'.

I tested this Regex in RegexHero before using in my code. It works correctly in regex Hero.

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with my regular expression.

**Update:**

I realized what the problem is:
I want the Regex to return true  only if the text between the first : and the first )  matches this pattern:  /[&/\w -]+\s*/

In my example string (ABC12: CPBI, OTCBB:CPAA)  there are two `:` and the regex is matching the text between 2nd : and )

How to modify this regex to enforce my requirement.

Comment: forward slashes must be escaped.  Your expression can be found with your example strings here: http://rubular.com/r/4ZFl3222jT with the only change of escaping the forward slash.  What is it doing that it should/shouldn't?

Comment: thanks for your comment. C sharp regex is able to handle the forward slash without escaping. Could be because regex pattern is enclosed in "" and not in // as in javascript. But your  rubular sample helped me  realize that it is matching the text between 2nd colon and ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick

```
(?<=\(\w+:)(\s*\w+)+(?=\))
```

I specified the first part `(ABC12:` with `\(\w+:`. I also replaced the middle part with the more specific one `(\s*\w+)+`.

Note also that within square brackets `[`  `]`, the special characters lose their meaning. Each character is taken as is.